# Orbeon Xform runner datefield

Tags: orbeon, xforms

We have the following code in the body. However, the three date fields appear on three rows in the form runner. We want them in the same row. Please help!

```
<xh:tr>
    <xh:td>
        <fr:fields-date xmlns="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
            xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl" id="procurement-contract-start-date-control"
            bind="procurement-contract-start-date-bind">
            <xf:label ref="$form-resources/procurement-contract-start-date/label"/>
            <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/procurement-contract-start-date/hint"/>
            <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
        </fr:fields-date>
    </xh:td>
</xh:tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the fields shown on the "same line" here:

[image: shown on the same line]

Maybe you're using some custom CSS the causes the fields to go on separate lines? If this doesn't help, I'd recommend you either update your question or post a new question with a minimal example that shows the issue you're having.